# Creating a pointer in an unusual way

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

I was looking for implementation of SCC algorithm in C++ and there's one weird line which is clearly beyond my comprehension.

```
Graph<V,E> gt(SIZE(g)), res(SIZE(g)), *tab[] = {this,&gt};
```

I don't understand `*tab[] = {this,&gt};`

I assume it is a pointer but still don't get it at all so I'd be glad If someone could explain it to me. I've been using C++ for almost 6 years and I've never seen this kind of pointer before.

Comment: It's the same as `int a = 1, *c = &a`

Comment: But `tab` is an array of pointers.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be three different declarations:

```
Graph<V,E> gt(SIZE(g));
Graph<V,E> res(SIZE(g));
Graph<V,E> *tab[] = {this,&gt};
```

It's probably someone's idea of making the code more minimal, but it arguably impacts readability in a pretty severe way.

Why `tab` even exists I don't know, it depends on how it's used in other parts of the code. Is this some kind of bizarro linked list?

Comment: I can share full code but There's lack of comments and there's more fancy notations.

Comment: Anyone who writes code like this is just being difficult on purpose. Sorry you have to work with it. I feel for you.

Comment: Most of competitive programming codes be like this :C I have to get on with it.

Comment: I'll share my results later.

Answer (score 1):

`tab` is an array of pointers to `Graph<V, E>`, and is initialized with two elements: pointer `this`, and a pointer to newly created `gt`.

Comment: Still don't get usage of this, I mean I know "this" is a pointer to an object itself for example in class. But array is not a class(?) This is very unclear.

Comment: It depends where this code appears, like inside a `class` or `struct`.